# Is there a simplified way to check each index of an string array?

Tags: php

For Example I have this string

```
$string = "HelloWorld";
```

And I want to check if the first four letters is equal to "Hell"

```
if($string[0]=="H"&&$string[1]=="e"&&$string[2]=="l"&&$string[3]=="l");
```

Is there a better or simplified way of checking this? maybe $string[0-4] or something like that

Comment: Will it always be the first four letters or will there be a time where you would want to check if the word "hell" exists in the string?

Comment: just use substring from start index from 0 and length is 4. then make an if comparison, or are you restricted from using functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to get the first N characters of your string you can use [substr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)

```
 i.e:
 $string = "HelloWorld";
 $rest   = substr($string , 0, 4);  // returns "Hell"
```

Or if you want to check if a word exists in the string you can also just use [strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)

```
i.e
$string = "HelloWorld";
$pos = strpos($string , 'Hell'); //will return false if word is not found in string
```